# Calculate APY given start balance, end balance, and term

Tags: compound-interest, apy

I'm having trouble figuring out the formula for calculating APY given a starting balance, ending balance, and term in length of years. What's the formula to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The formula for APY is essentially solving the future value (or present value) formula for the rate:

```
    end_bal = start_bal * (1+APY)^N
==> (1+APY)^N = (end_bal/start_bal)
==> 1+APY = (end_bal/start_bal)^(1/N)
==> APY = (end_bal/start_bal)^(1/N) - 1
```

Comment: Thank you! And am I correct to assume that N is number of periods?

Comment: Number of _years_. If you use compounding period other than years you'd need to adjust the formula slightly.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to go with the solution a friend gave me, since it gives me continuous compounding:

[image]

Comment: Note that your result is not exactly the APY. APY assumes annual compounding, not continuous. But you could easily convert your answer to annual compounding: `APY = e^r - 1`. Mathematically it ends up the same.

Comment: What would what I have be considered technically?

Comment: Technically, it’s continuous growth.  That’s great for a lot of things, but not finance.

Comment: What about estimating APY for a stock portfolio? Would that be continuous growth?

Comment: I think continuous is the right answer to the question "what is the effective APY for an investment that went from $a to $b in t years".

Comment: I.e., if you don't have a reason to pick a particular compounding period -- and for "effective interest rate" in the abstract, I don't think you do -- then "continuously" is the most natural choice. Also it would be slightly weird, I think, to compound less often than monthly and once you're at monthly it makes almost no further difference to go all the way to continuously so might as well. It's what's mathematically most elegant!